# replace delegate using block to pass value

Tags: iphone, ios, block

I have read so many positive things about using blocks - in particular that it simplifys the code by elimanting delegate calls. I have found examples where blocks are used at end of animation instead of delegate calls. the block example is easy but i cannot use the example to the iphone app.for example i use the delegate:

.h

```
@protocol AWActionSheetDelegate <NSObject>

- (int)numberOfItemsInActionSheet;
- (AWActionSheetCell*)cellForActionAtIndex:(NSInteger)index;
- (void)DidTapOnItemAtIndex:(NSInteger)index;

@end

@interface AWActionSheet : UIActionSheet

   @property (nonatomic, assign)id<AWActionSheetDelegate> IconDelegate;
-(id)initwithIconSheetDelegate:(id<AWActionSheetDelegate>)delegate ItemCount:(int)cout;
@end
```

.m

```
- (void)actionForItem:(UITapGestureRecognizer*)recongizer
{

   [IconDelegate DidTapOnItemAtIndex:cell.index];

}
```

and i use it :

```
 -(void)DidTapOnItemAtIndex:(NSInteger)index
{
    NSLog(@"tap on %d",index);

}
```

how use block not use delegate i  can get  the index,can you give advice and if  give good  block category to finish the effect is very good . i donot want to use delegate to pass the index,i only want to use block to get the index

Comment: To finish what ?? will you elaborate more ??

Comment: sorry for my english.my code is using delegate,i want to use block to finish the same effect

Comment: And delegates and blocks both have different work ...

Comment: yes，but i want to use block to get the index  in in another class after clicked on button .i do not want use delegate

Comment: hmm now I got you [Blocks or Delegation?](http://thejoeconwayblog.wordpress.com/2012/05/29/blocks-or-delegation/) link will help you ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for something like this:

```
//implementation for AWActionSheet's method: actionForItem:withBlock:

-(void) actionForItem:(UITapGestureRecognizer*)recongizer withBlock:(void(^)(NSInteger integer)) block {

    NSInteger myInt = 0;
    //whatever

    //callback
    block(myInt);
}
```

and the call

```
AWActionSheet* actionSheet;
[actionsheet actionForItem:recognizer withBlock:^(NSInteger integer) {
    NSLog(@"myInt: %d", integer);
}];
```

Comment: Can it take place of delegates ?? I mean how would one method call in another class when some action perform like what we can do using delegates and notifications ??? I would like to know

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding your question. It shouldn't take the place of delegates. With this code you can execute a method in object2 from object1 and when it finishes call another method (callback) on object1 passing a parameter from object2.

Comment: Yeah exactly thats what I want to tell @penwang but he is not getting .... BTW I haven't asked it  :) Thanks any way

Comment: @the Tiger is correct,your method only pass value,but not meet my  question,sorry for my english.i not only get the index,also perform some action to get the method.for example alertView have two ok button and cancel button,when i click the cancel button,i get the index=0,and also i can perform a action

Comment: I'm really not sure what you mean. Inside the callback block you can do whatever action you want.

Comment: @pengwang - I think Block is okay if you're doing in same class but you cant beat delegates by blocks ... delegates has different power.

Comment: You can send a block between classes, there's no problem with that. Delegates and blocks are not always interchangeable though.

Comment: @Odrakir - Thats what I asked you in first comment .... and I really want to know how to do that ?

Comment: The second piece of code I posted is doing that. From one class I call a method of another class and send a block.

Comment: In second class where you will have to write `[actionsheet actionForItem:recognizer withBlock:^(NSInteger integer) {
    NSLog(@"myInt: %d", integer);
}];` ??

Comment: Man! No. Please, check the docs. actionForItem:withBlock is a method from the second class. You can call that method from anywhere (even other classes) and send it a block.

Comment: In your code you're calling block your self by making class's object but what when you dont know when to call this method like when your webService has finished then it should call .... Like delegates method ... they call themselves ...

Comment: @ the tiger can understand the odrakir? i think my question the delegate not replace by the block

Answer (score 0):

Use this object:

https://github.com/matteogobbi/MGActionSheet

This is an easy example to init and use the object by block:

```
//Initialization
MGActionSheet *actionSheet = [[MGActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Block action sheet!" cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" destructiveButtonTitle:@"Delete" otherButtonTitles:@"Option 1", @"Option 2", @"Option 3", nil];

//Show with completition block
[actionSheet showInView:self.view withChoiceCompletition:^(int buttonIndex) {

    if(buttonIndex == actionSheet.cancelButtonIndex) NSLog(@"Cancelled");
    else if(buttonIndex == actionSheet.destructiveButtonIndex) NSLog(@"Destructed");
    else {
        NSLog(@"Option at index: %d", buttonIndex);
    }
}];
```